# Issue with click() - Dropdown is not expanding correctly

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm encountering an issue regarding the usage of the click() function in my script. I'm trying to click on a dropdown element to sort certain items after, but unfortunately, the click() function doesn't seem to be working at all.

Here's my code:

```
try {
    const dropdownContentSelector = '[data-testid="filter-dropdown--trigger"]';
    const dropdownOptionElements = await page.$$(dropdownContentSelector);

    await dropdownOptionElements[1].click();

    const sortOptionSelector = '#sort_by-list-item-price_low_to_high';
    await page.waitForSelector(dropdownContentSelector);

    console.log(dropdownOptionElements);

    await page.waitForSelector(sortOptionSelector);
    const sortOptionElement = await page.$(sortOptionSelector);

    await sortOptionElement.click();
} catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
}
```

What's really strange is that manually entering the following code in the browser console works correctly:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="filter-dropdown--trigger"]');
elements[1].click();
```

Could anyone explain why the click() function doesn't work for the first dropdown element? Is there a way to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: It's almost impossible to help without the site. That said, [if you have working browser code, maybe try slapping it into an `evaluate`](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#avoiding-pageevaluate-when-trusted-events-arent-necessary). `page.click()` [issues a trusted event that involves far greater complexity than browser node `.click()`](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#assuming-puppeteers-api-works-like-the-native-browser-api). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70401112/6243352) for example.